# Create a patch for core.libraries.yml

Tags: 8, version-control

I noticed that core/jquery.cookie is referencing the [jquery-cookie v1.4.1](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) library that is now no longer maintained. It is being superseded by [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and so I would like to write a Drupal core patch so that others can also have this feature.

The problem I am having is that I do not know how to properly apply a patch for something like this. I assume that I would have to modify the core.libraries.yml file to include the latest js-cookie, then I would have to include the minified JavaScript file into the assets/vendor directory such that the file is located in assets/vendor/jquery.jscookie/js.cookie.js while defining the library.

How would I download the js.cookie.js file into the assets/vendors/jquery.jscookie directory when I define the jquery.jscookie library?

My goal is to leave the existing `jquery.cookie` library so this patch would just need to define the `library` and add its `js` file into the appropriate directory.

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue in the Drupal issue queue first. Get some input on it before writing a patch.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I would encourage you to join [Drupal Slack](https://drupal.org/chat) and join the #contribute and #javascript channels. There are many core sub-system maintainers there that would be happy to answer questions. Additionally, what I did to look this up was to use git blame and then search for other similar issues such as https://www.drupal.org/node/289914, which should show you a good example of how that sort of issues flows. Most likely this issue would be more complex so asking in Slack about it would help.

Comment: @usernameabc, https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3042182, this issue seems pretty relevant.